# Cancel Cocoa Doc Based app Save method?

Tags: cocoa, document

How can I cancel the automatic display of the Save Panel when closing windows in a doc based Cocoa app?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: You'll have to tell us *why* you would want to do this: the save panel is shown if the document is "dirty" (i.e. has unsaved changes). Why, in God's name, would you want to close a document that the user has changed without showing them a save dialog? If your document initialization causes apparent changes and you want to make the new document appear clean instead of "dirty" to the NSDocument system, that's a different question. You'll have to give us a little more info to work with.

Comment: Using WebKit to build a custom browser module. I thought by using a doc based app it would be easier to support opening multiple pages at once. In this case there is no reason for a save option.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding `-isDocumentEdited`. This works for all open docs and is much simpler and safer than overriding `canCloseDocumentWithDelegate` or `canCloseAllDocumentsWithDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL) isDocumentEdited 
{
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For control on a per-window basis, override `-canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo:`

There's also similar methods on NSDocumentController for when there's more then one document with unsaved changes.

Agreed with Barry though, this is generally a bad idea.